# How do I link Odoo clickable statusbar with the workflow?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have defined state actions, buttons, and the workflow. They work just fine, the problem is when I tried to add a clickable statusbar and everytime I click the status bar, it won't actually do anything other than changing the record's state.

How do I link the statusbar to the workflow/actions?

model.py

```
def action_state_draft(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'draft' })
    return True

def action_state_confirmed(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'confirmed' })
    return True

def action_state_posted(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'posted' })
    return True

def action_state_cancelled(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'cancelled' })
    return True

def hello_world(self):
    print "Hello World!"

def hello_world_second(self):
    print "Hello World Second!"
```

model_view.xml

```
<header>
    <button name="action_state_confirmed" string="Confirm" states="draft" />
    <button name="action_state_posted" string="Post" states="confirmed" />
    <button name="action_state_cancelled" string="Cancel" states="draft,confirmed,posted" />
    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" clickable="True" statusbar_visible="draft,confirmed,posted,cancelled"/>
</header>
```

model_workflow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>      
        <record id="ig_account_voucher_wkf" model="workflow">
            <field name="name">ig.account.voucher.wkf</field>
            <field name="osv">ig.account.voucher</field>
            <field name="on_create">True</field>
        </record>

        <record id="act_draft" model="workflow.activity">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="ig_account_voucher_wkf"/>
            <field name="name">draft</field>
            <field name="flow_start">True</field>           
        </record>

        <record id="act_confirmed" model="workflow.activity">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="ig_account_voucher_wkf"/>
            <field name="name">confirmed</field>
            <field name="action">
                write({'state':'confirmed'})
                hello_world()
                hello_world_second()
            </field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
        </record>

        <record id="act_posted" model="workflow.activity">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="ig_account_voucher_wkf"/>
            <field name="name">posted</field>
            <field name="action">write({'state':'posted'})</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
        </record>

        <record id="act_posted" model="workflow.activity">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="ig_account_voucher_wkf"/>
            <field name="name">cancelled</field>
            <field name="action">write({'state':'cancelled'})</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
        </record>

        <record id="transition_draft_confirmed" model="workflow.transition">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_draft"/>
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_confirmed"/>
            <field name="condition">True</field>
            <field name="signal">action_state_confirmed</field>
        </record>

        <record id="transition_confirmed_posted" model="workflow.transition">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_confirmed"/>
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_posted"/>
            <field name="condition">True</field>
            <field name="signal">action_state_posted</field>
        </record>

        <record id="transition_confirmed_cancelled" model="workflow.transition">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_confirmed"/>
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_posted"/>
            <field name="condition">True</field>
            <field name="signal">action_state_cancelled</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Another relevant little question: Why do we need workflow instead of just using buttons and actions?

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have missing commas on workflow action when u pass the multiple method in workflow action.

please make is correct first

```
   <record id="act_confirmed" model="workflow.activity">
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="ig_account_voucher_wkf"/>
        <field name="name">confirmed</field>
        <field name="action">
            write({'state':'confirmed'}),
            hello_world(),
            hello_world_second()
        </field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
    </record>
```

Another Answer of your Question is :

**Why Work flow is needed instead of button ??**

The Main Goal is that the work flow is define as the business process flow.

Another goals are :

1. description of document evolution in time
2. automatic trigger of actions if some conditions are met
3. management of company roles and validation steps
4. management of interactions between the different objects/modules
5. graphical tool for visualization of document flows

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)

Comment: Nope, commas don't matter. Please take a look at this original Odoo file `/opt/odoo/addons/account/account_invoice_workflow.xml` line 25-28.

Comment: And still I couldn't get the statusbar to work. The buttons do work though.

Comment: you have to replace the field as state which u mention as the statusbar  using xpath u can replace that field and try to check again

Comment: It is already `state`. Take a look at my code snippet above. `<field name="state" widget="statusbar" clickable="True" statusbar_visible="draft,confirmed,posted,cancelled"/>`

Comment: yes definatelly but use the xpath to replase that one example                                            <xpath expr="//field[@name='state'] position='replace'>

Comment: <xpath expr="//field[@name='state'] position='replace'> 

<field name='state' widget="statusbar"  statusbar_visible="draft,confirmed,posted,cancelled,add_your_new_state_overhear_with_commas" />

</xpath>

Comment: I still don't believe in that workflows are always good idea, especially that several built-in Odoo modules don't use them.

Comment: @ÁronLőrincz main reason behind the workflow is manage our document on different different stages(like Quotation,Sale Order,Account Incoive paid) so that we can easily understand that flow of each document on stage.and more things is that in Odoo 8.0 or later version its may remove all the workflow related logic and all just add it as statusbar  widget on form view